# Angular function with "angular" or without "angular" as parameter

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a tabs directive and I have seen the following:

```
(function (angular) {

  'use strict';  

  angular.module('tabs', []);
  angular.module('tabs').directive('tabs', tabsDirective);
  ...

 })(angular)
```

And

```
(function () {

  'use strict';  

  angular.module('tabs', []);
  angular.module('tabs').directive('tabs', tabsDirective);
  ...

 })()
```

What is the difference between `(function (angular) { })(angular)` and `(function () { })()`

Comment: The first passes a reference to angular into the IIFE and then returns the reference. The second does not. As i understand it, the reference to angular in the second example is not necessary when angular is loaded by the browser and attached to the window as a global.

Comment: @Miguel have you read my answer?

Comment: @PankajParkar Just now and marked it as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Miguel thank you..cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both stands for `IIFE` pattern, 1st pattern only does self calling function which is taking global `angular` object. Where as in 2nd approach are passing parameters to while evaluating self calling function, and passing global parameter while calling function. Those global parameter will become local to function. Inner context of function will directly access passed global variable. Here its `angular`.

I'd suggest you to follow 2nd approach. Because local variables are faster to resolve than the global variables, but this is on a huge scale and you’ll never notice the speed increase - but also worth considering if we’re referencing our `globals` a lot!

```
(function (angular) { 
   a.module('app',[])
   .....
})(angular)
```

Additional benefit would be, It save your some bytes while doing minification process, Just by having like

```
(function (a, b) { //and  
   a.module('app',[])
   .....
})(window, angular)
```

[**Great article**](http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/) to have more information on it.